# How to read rsav file in R

Tags: r

I have a file with extension `rsav`, what is the type of this file? How could I read it properly in R? I found bearly not so much files regarding this type of file from Google.

Thanks in adavnce.

The following is the description of question:

Find (on Canvas) the file “file.rsav” (which can be loaded into R using load(“file.rsav”)).
It contains a time series (“xx”). The series is a “demeaned” monthly revenue stream (in millions of dollars) for a company. There are n = 96 observations.

```
df = load('./file.rsav')
print(df)
```

Out:

```
[1] "xx"
```

With load function:

```
load('./file.rsav'); ls()
```

Out:

```
 [1] "agg"                    "air_reserve"            "air_store"             
......             

[139] "wdi"                    "world"                  "xx"
```

With `str(xx)`, it generates:

```
 Time-Series [1:96] from 1 to 8.92: 2.45 2.18 0.389 -1.44 -1.47 ...
```

With `xx`, it generates:

```
          Jan         Feb         Mar         Apr         May         Jun         Jul
1  2.45017780  2.17955829  0.38874020 -1.43979552 -1.47049807 -2.25233354 -0.82580703
2  1.92378321  1.87944208  1.07382472  1.01933130  1.88660307 -0.31109156 -0.25732342
3  0.60732330  1.53185399  1.58614371  0.63922270  0.82728407  0.28910411 -1.18154941
4  0.41375543  1.96633332  1.97402973  4.16058136  5.15474250  5.71865844  3.93136013
5 -1.51228022 -3.03396294 -3.65446772 -4.69589618 -3.51276584 -2.97682246 -3.08655352
6  3.43027017  4.68909032  6.55598795  4.95816124  4.87626503  3.17103291  0.79093946
7 -0.62481997 -0.94469455 -2.13648402 -3.64364158 -2.07214317 -3.26793808 -3.38573375
8  0.67823828  1.09908274  0.93832242  0.08791237  1.77322327  2.01201710  3.70197246
          Aug         Sep         Oct         Nov         Dec
1  0.53048061  1.31994246  0.69306401  1.25916404  1.53363966
2 -0.47154459  0.52849630  0.90548093  0.71783457  0.86908457
3 -0.52525201 -0.40335058  0.73415310  0.58501633  0.29875228
4  2.50242432  1.69408297  0.96230124  0.53164036 -0.64480235
5 -1.60735865 -0.20500888 -0.44508903 -0.01443040  1.71087427
6 -0.09975821 -0.85972650 -0.41557374 -0.99876068  0.52620555
7 -2.25968715 -0.91700127 -0.49302872 -1.44275203 -0.66221559
8  4.62724761  4.17549847  3.43992950  3.15302462  4.17300576
```

Comment: I suspect whoever wrote that question decided arbitrarily to use the `.rsav` extension for a file they wrote with `save()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects are already created in the global env with `load`.  So, just use

```
head(xx)
str(xx) # gives the structure
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this data structure. How can I convert it as dataframe?

Comment: @ahbon I guess you have a time series object (`ts`)?  You can wrap with `as.data.frame`, i.e. `as.data.frame(ts(rnorm(52), freq = 12))`

Comment: Yes, here is the rest part of question: `The series has been “demeaned”; usually that would mean we subtract off X¯ from every data point, but pretend for now we know the mean µ exactly so we have subtracted off µ from every data point, so the new series is exactly (theoretically) mean 0. (But thus its sample mean is not precisely 0.) We will consider possible ARMA models for the series Xt. We assume that the corresponding white noise is Gaussian (so Xt is Gaussian).`

Comment: @ahbon It looks like a statement more than a question

Comment: I update the outputs of `str(xx)` and `xx`, please check.

Comment: @ahbon Yes, i saw that, but your new question is not clear to me.  It is a time series object and it can be used for building modelss

Comment: Sorry, you're right, this is the question: I was asked to `Compute forecasts backcasts using Model 1 (which is AR(2) model, Xt = .1.34Xt 1 .48Xt 2 + Wt, Wt iid∼ N(0, σ2).), up to 25 time steps in the future and into the past. Write code to do the prediction by hand (i.e., not using the predict() function). Plot the data, forecast, and 95% prediction intervals [assuming gaussianity] (all on one plot)`.

Comment: @ahbon could you please ask that as a new question and I am assuming that it falls under the scope of `stats.stackexchange.com`

Comment: Thank you, I raise a new question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/455648/write-r-code-of-ar2-model-for-a-time-serie-data-from-rsav-file